# A word for a squared layout of differently shaped objects

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

I am looking for a word which describes a layout of differently shaped and oriented objects that are all square relative to each other, and which leaves a minimum but necessary amount of space between each object.

These images are examples of the type of layout I mean:

[image: headphones, wallet, phone, watch, etc]

[image: watch, clippers, bracelet, keys knife]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're talking about the trend of laying stuff on the ground and taking a picture, you're referring to a **flat lay**.

Comment: I learned something new as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a branch of mathematical optimization problems called [packing problems.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems)  Your layout would be called a "rectangular packing".  In a mathematical algorithm, the empty space between objects would be achieved just by padding the object sizes with a border before running the optimization.

Comment: I was wondering if maybe they wanted a mathematical answer.  In that case, would **tessellation** be correct?

Comment: Tessellations are tilings of the plane and thus infinite, so I'd say **packing** is more appropriate here.